# How to properly join these four tables in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm currently creating a small application, where users can subscribe to different channels to see the corresponding posts.

My database looks like this (simplified):
[image]

Now I'm trying to get all the information out of the post table (all columns), for all the posts that are connected to any channel a specific user may have subscribed.

Example: A user (id_user = 0) has subsribed to three channels (id_channel = 1, 2 and 3) and now wants to see all posts in these channels (each post where fk_channel = 1 or 2 or 3).

I tried many variations using different joins, however I couldn't manage to find the correct query. One of my last attempts looked something like this (which does not work...):

```
SELECT * FROM posts
INNER JOIN channels ON posts.fk_channel = channels.id_channel
INNER JOIN subscriptions ON channels.id_channel = subscriptions.fk_subcribed_channel
INNER JOIN users ON subscriptions.fk_subscibed_by = users.id_user
```

Comment: What will the final output look like? Also the table appears to be CHANNELS not CHANNEL.

Comment: Please see: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Answer (score 1):

If you have the user's id then there is no need to join the table `users`, because you can use the column `fk_subscibed_by` of `subscriptions`:

```
SELECT p.* 
FROM subscriptions s
INNER JOIN channels c ON c.id_channel = s.fk_subcribed_channel
INNER JOIN posts p ON p.fk_channel = c.id_channel
WHERE s.fk_subscibed_by = 0
```

If you want to get all the columns of the joined tables, use `SELECT *` instead of `SELECT p.*` which returns only the columns from `posts`.

Answer (score 0):

If your rappresentation is right this should work properly:

```
SELECT * FROM posts
LEFT OUTER JOIN channel ON posts.fk_channel = channel.id_channel
LEFT OUTER subscriptions ON channel.id_channel = subscriptions.fk_subcribed_channel
LEFT OUTER users ON subscriptions.fk_subscibed_by = users.id_user
```

Like this you should be able to get each post from each channel the user is subscribed.